# When is the SQL Server database ready to accept queries?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, startup

In the SQL Server error log file I found the following lines:

```
2018-02-22 14:10:58.95 spid17s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
2018-02-22 14:10:58.95 spid16s     Starting up database 'ReportServer'.
2018-02-22 14:10:58.95 spid18s     Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
2018-02-22 14:10:58.95 spid19s     Starting up database 'XYZ'.
```

If I check for the status of the database XYZ before this time, it is `ONLINE` using the following statement:

```
SELECT state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name='XYZ'
```

...but when I try to connect to this database using a C# application, it can't connect to the database.

The error is:

> Login failed for user 'asd'.
>   Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.

I tried three different users (Windows user, sa, SQL Server user defined for the application). The problem happens when I run the application in the start up of the OS, but if I start it manually after the start up, no errors happen, so I think all SQL Server settings and firewall settings are correct.

I also checked before this that the service status is running.

What else should I check to make sure the database is actually online and ready for queries?

I'm looking for a key that tells me it's ok to query the database, instead of delaying for a time (even not based on a clear reason).

I thought of scanning the error log for the text "Starting up database 'XYZ'", but this means I have to add a setting for the application for the path of the SQL Server error log. It also means reading the file many times until I find this phrase.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The SQL Server database is ready to accept queries as soon as:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'database name', 'Collation')
```

does not return `NULL`.

From the documentation for [`DATABASEPROPERTYEX` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql):

> Note: The `ONLINE` status may be returned while the database is being opened and is not yet recovered. To identify when a database can accept connections, query the Collation property of `DATABASEPROPERTYEX`. The database can accept connections when the database collation returns a non-null value. For Always On databases, query the `database_state` or `database_state_desc` columns of `sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states`.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server databases start up, but then they need to analyze the transaction log to roll transactions forward & backward. This process can take anywhere from milliseconds to hours (even days!) in the event of a long-running transaction, many (think thousands) of user databases, or databases with lots (think tens of thousands) of virtual log files.

**If you only want the app to get in when recovery is done and the database is ready,** have the application retry its connection.

**If you want the app to be able to get into SQL Server immediately,** but maybe not be able to run any queries yet, set its default database to TempDB instead of a user database. It'll likely be online right away even when user databases are unavailable.